# Is there any way to have struct-2 variables in struct-1, if struct-2 is declared after struct-1?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

I'm having a set of points that are all part of the line segments. So I want to create a struct for the *point*, such that it will have a variable pointing to the *line* it is a part of.

```
template<typename T>
struct point{
    int x,y;
    T* ln;
};

struct line{
    point U,L;
};

point a;
a.x = 1;
a.y = 1;

point b;
b.x = 0;
b.y = 0;
    
line seg1;
seg1.U = a;
seg1.L = b;
    
a.ln = seg1;
b.ln = seg1;
```

In the code, I get the following error:

> `'invalid use of template-name 'point' without an argument list'`

I don't think this is how we should approach this problem. I do see a few problems with this like when creating a *point* in the *line* struct, *T* is unknown (I tried adding a constructor but that doesn't seem to work too).
Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: "This dosen't seem to work" What is problem? Please be specific and copy-paste the compiler error if any.

Comment: It doesn't work because "point U,L;" is not a valid way to instantiate a template that has one template parameter.

Comment: is the template your attempt to solve your issue of `line` not being visible from `point`?

Comment: yes, I was trying to solve it with templates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need templates, you just need a forward declaration.

```
struct line;  // this is a forward declaration

struct point{
    int x,y;
    line* ln;
};

// ...
a.ln = &seg1;
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails to compile because you are not specifying a type for the template parameter `T` when declaring instances of `point`, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct point{
    int x,y;
    T* ln;
};

struct line{
    point<line> U,L; // <--
};

point<line> a; // <--
a.x = 1;
a.y = 1;

point<line> b; // <--
b.x = 0;
b.y = 0;
    
line seg1;
seg1.U = a;
seg1.L = b;
    
a.ln = &seg1;
b.ln = &seg1;
```